# JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag error when actually it exist

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

I am getting following  check style error

```
[ERROR] src\main\java\com\disney\wdpr\dclm\personalization\base\service\mapper\PaymentSvcMapper.java:[45,46] (javadoc) JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag for 'retrievePersonByPersonIdPayerResponse'.
[ERROR] src\main\java\com\disney\wdpr\dclm\personalization\base\service\mapper\PaymentSvcMapper.java:[46,33] (javadoc) JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag for 'fidelioPostResponse'.
[ERROR] src\main\java\com\disney\wdpr\dclm\personalization\base\service\mapper\PaymentSvcMapper.java:[46,62] (javadoc) JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag for 'personId'.
[ERROR] src\main\java\com\disney\wdpr\dclm\personalization\base\service\mapper\PaymentSvcMapper.java:[46,89] (javadoc) JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag for 'blist'.
[ERROR] src\main\java\com\disney\wdpr\dclm\personalization\base\service\mapper\PaymentSvcMapper.java:[46,103] (javadoc) JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag for 'paymentType'.
[ERROR] src\main\java\com\disney\wdpr\dclm\personalization\base\service\mapper\PaymentSvcMapper.java:[47,21] (javadoc) JavadocMethod: Expected @param tag for 'routedPId'.
```

But my code contains @param tags in the specified function and line numbers.

```
/**
 * @param retrievePersonByPersonIdPayerResponse
 * @param fidelioPostResponse
 * @param personId
 * @param blist
 * @param paymentType
 * @param routedPId
 * @return
 */
public static PaymentResponse mapPaymentRequest(
        RetrievePersonByPersonIdResponse retrievePersonByPersonIdPayerResponse,
        FidelioPostResponse fidelioPostResponse, Integer personId, HashSet<Integer> blist, String paymentType,
        Integer routedPId) {
```

Please advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because you just list the arguments, but don't explain them. Your javadoc is a waste of space, it doesn't add anything that is not already there in code.

Here is a minimal example:

```java
public class Test {
    /**
     * @param theFoo what to foo
     */
    public String foo(String theFoo) {
        return theFoo;
    }
}
```

When I run `javadoc` on it, I get a similar complaint:

```sh
robert:~$ javadoc Test.java
Loading source file Test.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 14.0.1
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating ./Test.html...
Test.java:3: warning: no description for @param
     * @param theFoo
       ^
Test.java:5: warning: no @return
    public String foo(String theFoo) {
                  ^
...
```

Just add a bit of explanation to fix it:

```
public class Test {
    /**
     * @param theFoo what to foo
     * @return the same foo
     */
    public String foo(String theFoo) {
        return theFoo;
    }
}
```

You don't get a warning about it, but honestly, your Javadoc should explain what the method does, above the first `@param`.

Comment: @JishnuPrathap Did you try and add a description?